# perfect fit for a Postgres function or not (and how)?

Tags: postgresql, activerecord

I'm working on this kind of data structure :

[image]

Now, say I have to search for products that are < 90 EUR, it should only returns the product "item2". On the other hand, if I search for products that are == 100 EUR, I should only returns the product "item1".

I have 60 000 products and 16 currencies, so I just can't convert all products in all currencies on a daily basis (as the currency rates updates daily) only to be able to perform this search.

I have 2 questions :

- is this use case a good fit for a Postgres function ? Is there any other good and sustainable solution if not ?
- if a postgres function is the solution. Given that I'm using Ruby on Rails (4.2) and the search requests (on products sizes, colors etc...) are chained using ActiveRecord : is the call to the DB function still chainable and usable in AR ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Why on earth is your exchange rate table using `hstore`? Are you trying to store an m:n relationship in some flattened form?

Comment: Simple : since I don't need to perform any search into those rates, using hstore I can add/remove currencies on the fly without having to create/remove columns.

Comment: Er. `(from_currency, to_currency, rate)` ? Store tuples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record, I ended up creating a new column "price_eur" in the "products" table where I convert each price to EUR whatever is the original currency. Doing so I can perform a consistent search based on this price_eur column.

I just wanted to know if there was an alternative solution but looks like there is no other simple way...

Answer (score 1):

Using a function for this is a *terrible* idea, because performance will suffer greatly: the exchange rates will change over time, rendering your indexes useless.

Further, it's a terrible idea to store a single price per item. Thing psychological prices and tax considerations: if something is €99.99 including VAT in the Eurozone, it'll probably make sense to sell it for $99.99 plus sales tax in the US. No amount of exchange rate manipulation using functions or other will change that. (Compare the prices of Apple in the US, in France, in the UK, etc.).

For each item, associate a price in Euros, one in Dollars, etc. -- each with a currency_id, and have the exchange rates reside in a separate table. Or create some kind of price-list table in which you associate prices based on currency (e.g. €99 = $99) to a price_id, and associate the products (it's actually the SKU, btw) to their corresponding price_id.

You can fill this data in semi-automatically using an exchange rate table, and periodically update them using one as well. But really: do reserve the ability to manually set prices, make sure you mark prices as including or excluding tax. And when it comes to taxes, don't forget that tax rates are different from a place to the next and from a product to the next.

Comment: Thank you Denis, but I'm afraid I ain't got no choice about the business rules : the app is a kind of ebay or airbnb like where each user sells its own product at its own price in the user's currency. I've over simplified here to make it simple to understand.